# How to make facebook type share?

Tags: php, facebook

How to make facebook type wall share for social networking site?

I need suggestion what to do and how to do in php i am trying to make something like a form with input box and submit=share button when user click on share button the text store and display on another iframe on same page in a pre define format

Thank you so much

**Note:for those who want to close and down vote this question please comment out whats wrong in this question so that maybe in future i don't commit the same mistake thanks...**

Comment: This question is very broad. Questions on this site are [supposed to be specific problems](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask), and almost always a programming question.

Comment: @jprofitt thank you so much so what do you suggest close or delete this question and ask it on programming site ?

Comment: @jprofitt i am glad to see your comment 
because i think when some one comment on your mistakes is those who want that you don't do mistake in future thanks again :)

Comment: @jprofitt this question is revised and its not programming site question as per  Yannis Rizos from programming site 
:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not rocket science, particularly if you use something like [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com).  Their [second video tutorial](http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/watch/blog/) shows the basics of doing what you want.

Comment: k thanks for answer and effort can you please explain me how and what can i done with CodeIgniter thanks again